# How to get a component name from backing bean to use with p:component

Tags: dynamic, primefaces

I need to update different component based on from where the page is invoked.

```
<p:commandButton id="questionnaire_save_button"
 value="#{shop_msgs['questionnaire.save.button.label']}"                               
 action="#{questionnaireBean.update(questionnaire)}"                              
 update=":#{p:component(#{questionnaireBean.refreshComponentId})}" />
```

In my Questionnaire bean I have the following method:

```
public String getRefreshComponentId() {
refreshComponentId = "";
if(isFromCCRM()) {
 refreshComponentId ="questionnaires_wrapper_panel";
 }else {
   refreshComponentId = "breadcrumbs_panel";
  }
  return refreshComponentId;
```

}

However I keep getting syntax error:
Caused by: javax.el.ELException: Error Parsing: :#{p:component(#{questionnaireBean.refreshComponentId})}
    at org.jboss.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createNodeInternal(ExpressionBuilder.java:130)
    at org.jboss.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.build(ExpressionBuilder.java:151)
    at org.jboss.el.lang.ExpressionBuilder.createValueExpression(ExpressionBuilder.java:195)
    at org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl.createValueExpression(ExpressionFactoryImpl.java:68)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.TagAttributeImpl.getValueExpression(TagAttributeImpl.java:385)
    ... 117 more
Caused by: org.jboss.el.parser.ParseException: Encountered "{" at line 1, column 17.
Was expecting one of:
    "." ...
    ")" ...
    "[" ...
    "," ...
    ">" ...
    "gt" ...
    "<" ...
    "lt" ...
    ">=" ...
    "ge" ...
    "<=" ...
    "le" ...
    "==" ...
    "eq" ...
    "!=" ...
    "ne" ...
    "&&" ...
    "and" ...
    "||" ...
    "or" ...
    "*" ...
    "+" ...
    "-" ...
    "?" ...
    "/" ...
    "div" ...
    "%" ...
    "mod" ...
    "(" ..

Answer (score 4):

Change:

```
update=":#{p:component(#{questionnaireBean.refreshComponentId})}" />
```

to:

```
update=":#{p:component(questionnaireBean.refreshComponentId)}"
```